USBに保存したプログラムがターミナルで実行できない
ラズパイで参考書に載っているような温湿度計を作ろうとしていますが、cronで自動実行できません。
タイトルにある通り、ラズパイ本体のメモリを考慮して、作成したプログラムをUSBに保存しています。
何度パスを打ち直しても実行されないので、ターミナルに
python3 /media/admin/A11E-91493/rasp plogram/chapt6.py

と書いて、直接実行しようとしたら,
no such file or directory
と言われました。
そこで、findでファイル検索をかけてみましたが、やはりどのように検索しても、そのようなファイルはありません、と出ます。
温湿度を計測するプログラムは正常に動きますし、同じプログラムをラズパイ本体に保存してやってみると、cronでの自動実行もできました。
できる限り、USBでできるようにしたいのですが、ターミナルは外部メディアなどにはアクセスできないのでしょうか。それとも、ただパスが間違っているだけなのでしょうか。
初心者質問で恐縮ですが、ご回答のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

パスの記載について、「/media/admin/A11E-91493/rasp plogram/chapt6.py」は途中に空白がありますか? (あるいは誤記ですか?)

パスの途中に空白の入ったフォルダ(rasp plogram)があるからでは？ フォルダ名を空白の無い物に変えてみてはどうでしょう？ あとplogramってprogramのスペルミスでは？

ご回答ありがとうございます。コメントや回答にあった空白は誤字ではなくそのように設定していたものです。空白が問題とのことでしたので、空白を消したファイル名に変更したところ、findもcronも動かすことができました。ご回答ありがとうございます！

コメント通りに空白の問題かもしれません。まずは find というコマンドを使う時：
sudo find / -name "chapt6.py"

この形を使えば、もしこのファイルがあると見つかれます。sudo を使わなくても大丈夫だけど、ログは読みにくくなります。
そして、空白のこと：
python3 /media/admin/A11E-91493/rasp\ plogram/chapt6.py

または
python3 "/media/admin/A11E-91493/rasp plogram/chapt6.py"

で空白があるパスのファイルを実行ができます。
